# How can i convert mysql Workbench view to look like SQL server manager?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I like MySql Workbench but I am looking for a way to make it's view somewhat similar to SQL Server management.
1) instead of having one windows for error output and one window for the results, I would like to put both on the same page. so if there is an error i see the error but if there is not error i see the results in the same window.
2) Is there a way to separate the tree view on the left so that view and on their own node instead of having them all mixed up with the tables?

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these wishes are possible currently. You can however open feature requests for them on http://bugs.mysql.com, so we can take them into consideration.